Pronunciation of initialisms from early-stressed compounds
Orange juice is early-stressed, but initialisms are usually late-stressed (e.g., CIA /ˌsiaɪˈeɪ/), so how is OJ pronounced?
Compare knockout /ˈnɒk aʊt/ and KO  /ˌkeɪ ˈəʊ/

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Aren't a lot of initialisms pronounced with uniform stress? UN; CIA; CNN; ADHD; ASAP ...

Good question. I hadn't thought about it before, but the generalization that acronyms are late-stressed doesn't seem to apply (at least, not invariably) to cases like this: I accent OJ "orange juice" on the first syllable ([ˈoʊdʒeɪ]).
I'm not sure how relevant it is that "orange juice" is early-stressed. The accent of an acronym is not always in the same place as the unabbreviated phrase: I accent the first syllable of operating system and air conditioner but the last syllable of OS and AC. I accent the first syllable of television but the second syllable of TV: apparently, some people accent the first, which suggests there aren't any hard-and-fast rules.

Actually Longman gives for both AmE and BrE as the primary pronunciation  /ˈteləˌvɪʒən /

And AC for air-conditioning isn't the same as AC for alternating current, possibly because there is an implied comparison with DC.

OJ is equally stressed as the words: Oh jay. And we say to stress or place the tonic stress on some word or syllable, the verb accent here doesn't work for me at all.

I suspect it's relevant that, while one might contrast OJ with other kinds of juice, one wouldn't contrast an AC with other kinds of conditioning.
